# PythonRDD.collect() failure

Tags: python, apache-spark, mapreduce, rdd

I want to implement the algorithm of CCF-iterate with secondary sorting explained in the article : [https://www.cse.unr.edu/~hkardes/pdfs/ccf.pdf](https://www.cse.unr.edu/%7Ehkardes/pdfs/ccf.pdf)

This is my code :

```
rdd = sc.parallelize([(1, 2), (2, 3), (2, 4), (4, 5), (6, 7), (7, 8)])

num_iterations = 5

def map_func(pair):
    key, value = pair
    yield (key, value)
    yield (value, key)

def reduce_func(key, values):
    min_value = next(values)
    if min_value < key:
        yield (key, min_value)
        for value in values:
            yield (value, min_value)

for i in range(num_iterations):
    mapped_rdd = rdd.flatMap(map_func)

    updated_rdd = mapped_rdd.groupByKey().flatMap(lambda x: reduce_func(x[0], sorted(x[1])))

    dedup_rdd = updated_rdd.distinct()

    mapped_rdd_2 = dedup_rdd.flatMap(lambda x: [(x[0], x[1]), (x[1], x[0])])

    updated_rdd_2 = mapped_rdd_2.groupByKey().flatMap(lambda x: reduce_func(x[0], sorted(x[1])))

    rdd = updated_rdd_2.distinct()

print(rdd.collect())
```

I am doing this on jupyter so i know that everything runs perfectly until the last line for rdd.collect(), here is my error :

```
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-32-4ff2a94bd2aa> in <module>
----> 1 rdd.collect()

C:\dev\tools\Python36\lib\site-packages\pyspark\rdd.py in collect(self)
    948         """
    949         with SCCallSiteSync(self.context) as css:
--> 950             sock_info = self.ctx._jvm.PythonRDD.collectAndServe(self._jrdd.rdd())
    951         return list(_load_from_socket(sock_info, self._jrdd_deserializer))
    952 

C:\dev\tools\Python36\lib\site-packages\py4j\java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1320         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
   1321         return_value = get_return_value(
-> 1322             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1323 
   1324         for temp_arg in temp_args:

C:\dev\tools\Python36\lib\site-packages\py4j\protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    326                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    327                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
--> 328                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    329             else:
    330                 raise Py4JError(

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 250.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 250.0 (TID 90) (LDS09030.mshome.net executor driver): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\dev\tools\SPARK\spark-3.3.2-bin-hadoop3\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\worker.py", line 686, in main
  File "C:\dev\tools\SPARK\spark-3.3.2-bin-hadoop3\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\worker.py", line 676, in process
  File "C:\dev\tools\Python36\lib\site-packages\pyspark\rdd.py", line 2918, in pipeline_func
    return func(split, prev_func(split, iterator))
  File "C:\dev\tools\Python36\lib\site-packages\pyspark\rdd.py", line 2918, in pipeline_func
    return func(split, prev_func(split, iterator))
  File "C:\dev\tools\Python36\lib\site-packages\pyspark\rdd.py", line 417, in func
    return f(iterator)
  File "C:\dev\tools\Python36\lib\site-packages\pyspark\rdd.py", line 2236, in combine
    merger.mergeValues(iterator)
  File "C:\dev\tools\SPARK\spark-3.3.2-bin-hadoop3\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\shuffle.py", line 253, in mergeValues
    for k, v in iterator:
  File "<ipython-input-30-9512485ad7e4>", line 15, in reduce_func
TypeError: 'list' object is not an iterator

    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.handlePythonException(PythonRunner.scala:552)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$3.read(PythonRunner.scala:758)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$3.read(PythonRunner.scala:740)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:505)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$GroupedIterator.fill(Iterator.scala:1211)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$GroupedIterator.hasNext(Iterator.scala:1217)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.write(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:140)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.ShuffleWriteProcessor.write(ShuffleWriteProcessor.scala:59)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:136)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:548)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1504)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:551)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:2672)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2(DAGScheduler.scala:2608)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:2607)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:2607)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1(DAGScheduler.scala:1182)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:1182)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:407)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:1182)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2860)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2802)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2791)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:952)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2238)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2259)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2278)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2303)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$collect$1(RDD.scala:1021)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:406)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:1020)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.collectAndServe(PythonRDD.scala:180)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe(PythonRDD.scala)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor59.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\dev\tools\SPARK\spark-3.3.2-bin-hadoop3\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\worker.py", line 686, in main
  File "C:\dev\tools\SPARK\spark-3.3.2-bin-hadoop3\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\worker.py", line 676, in process
  File "C:\dev\tools\Python36\lib\site-packages\pyspark\rdd.py", line 2918, in pipeline_func
    return func(split, prev_func(split, iterator))
  File "C:\dev\tools\Python36\lib\site-packages\pyspark\rdd.py", line 2918, in pipeline_func
    return func(split, prev_func(split, iterator))
  File "C:\dev\tools\Python36\lib\site-packages\pyspark\rdd.py", line 417, in func
    return f(iterator)
  File "C:\dev\tools\Python36\lib\site-packages\pyspark\rdd.py", line 2236, in combine
    merger.mergeValues(iterator)
  File "C:\dev\tools\SPARK\spark-3.3.2-bin-hadoop3\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\shuffle.py", line 253, in mergeValues
    for k, v in iterator:
  File "<ipython-input-30-9512485ad7e4>", line 15, in reduce_func
TypeError: 'list' object is not an iterator

    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.handlePythonException(PythonRunner.scala:552)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$3.read(PythonRunner.scala:758)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$3.read(PythonRunner.scala:740)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:505)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$GroupedIterator.fill(Iterator.scala:1211)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$GroupedIterator.hasNext(Iterator.scala:1217)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.write(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:140)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.ShuffleWriteProcessor.write(ShuffleWriteProcessor.scala:59)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:136)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:548)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1504)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:551)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    ... 1 more
```

Can somebody help me ?

Comment: Just to help with debugging; error is not actually from last line but stack trace indicates `File "<ipython-input-30-9512485ad7e4>", line 15, in reduce_func
TypeError: 'list' object is not an iterator`. Due to lazy nature of actual execution only gets triggered with `.collect()` call.
`updated_rdd.collect()` should help you pinpoint error better.

Comment: sorted() https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted returns a list, when called inside `reduce_func()`. This list object causes error `TypeError: 'list' object is not an iterator` during call of `next(values)`.